# Using OkHttpClient with Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, okhttp, android-networking

Is it a good idea to use OkHttpClient to do all the networking (GET/PUT/POST) and display the response (HTML/JS Body) in the Android WebView.

I have attempted this on iOS using Alamofire to fetch the data and display the data in UIWebView and haven't met any issue. However, while researching online I find mixed results with the compatibility of custom HttpClients + Android WebView. Primarily, I am seeing that webview's shouldInterceptRequest method doesn't provide all the data like body in POST reponse.

I would like to know if it's still a bad idea to use a custom HTTPClient with Android WebView in newer Android version (Android K+). If yes, then what are the technical limitations behind this.